# Config new laravel route but it show me 404 error except default route

Tags: laravel, macos, mamp

I want to config a laravel 5.2 routes in `routes.php` but it shows **404 error** except default route that already exists when I install laravel.

You can see my configuration in images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use the following syntax for adding new routes to routes.php:
`Route::get('/new-route', 'controller@method');`
`Route::get('/new-route-2', function (Request $request){//add code});`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Best to paste in the link text rather than an image link, that may later be broken.